# Android - Problems with animate() in different screen sizes

Tags: java, android, jquery-animate

Im having this problem with the animate() in different screen sizes. I was testing everything in my s9+ and when i tested the same on a Moto g3 the layouts that i animated with animate().translationY were a disaster.
So i googled a little bit and of course i was doing the things in a wrong way. I found here that i have to use this piece of code:

```
Float distance = TypedValue.applyDimension(
                TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 770,
                getResources().getDisplayMetrics()
        );
```

(770) is my value.

And then `cardViewBottom.animate().translationY(distance).setDuration(1);`

But i am not having a good result. In my s9+ 770 is the correct value, and in my moto g3 (smaller device) is 560 the value. I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
val metrics = DisplayMetrics()
windowManager?.defaultDisplay?.metrics(metrics)
val width = metrics.density

val distance = TypedValue.applyDimension(
                TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, width,
                resources.displayMetrics)
```

Not sure what TypedValue.applyDimension's params are
If you need pixels then `metrics.widthPixels`

Comment: This is Android, Java. This is not for android i think.

Comment: This is Kotlin the official language of Android.

It is almost the same thing just add some verbosity and these ().

Comment: just type it like Java... like DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();

and getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().... etc.

Comment: Oh, i did it before to test something. In this case above, metrics.density will show me the entire screen size, isn't it?

Comment: It will get the width of the screen in dp.

Comment: Glad to see that helped.